# Correct item in array not always deleted. React context

Tags: reactjs

I have a delete function in my Context that I'm passing ids to so I can delete components from the array however it doesn't always work correctly. If I add 3 note components to the board for example, it will always delete the last item on the board.  If I add a to do list in between 2 notes, they'll delete correctly.  There are 2 console logs and the deleted one shows the correct deleted item, and components shows the 2 that are left. Again, if there are 3 notes, it deletes the last item everytime, but if I do one note, one to do, then one note again, the correct item on the board is deleted.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import ComponentReducer from "./ComponentReducer";

const NewComponentState: NewComponentsState = {
  components: [],
  addComponent: () => {},
  deleteComponent: () => {},
};

export const NewComponentContext =
  React.createContext<NewComponentsState>(NewComponentState);

export const NewComponentProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState(NewComponentState.components);

    const deleteComponent = (id: any) => {
      
      for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {

           if(components[i].id === id) {
             let deleted = components.splice(i, 1)
             console.log(deleted)
             setComponents([...components])
             console.log(components)
           } 
      }
    }
   const addComponent = (newComponent: any) => {
     setComponents([...components, newComponent])
   }
  return (
    <NewComponentContext.Provider
      value={{ components, deleteComponent, addComponent }}
    >
      {children}
    </NewComponentContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Board component

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { NewComponentContext } from "../Context/NewComponentContext";
import NewComponentMenu from "./NewComponents/NewComponentMenu";
import Note from "./NewComponents/Note/Note";
import Photo from "./NewComponents/Photo/Photo";
import TodoList from "./NewComponents/Todo/TodoList";

const newComponents: any = {
  1: TodoList,
  2: Photo,
  3: Note
}
const Board = () => {
    const { components } = useContext(NewComponentContext);

    const componentList  = components.map((component, i) => {
      const id: number = component.componentType
      const NewComponent = newComponents[id]
      
      for (const property in newComponents) {
          const value = parseInt(property)
          if (value == id) {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                <NewComponent id={component.id}/>
              </div>
            )
          }
      }
    });
  
    return (
      <div className="flex space-x-10 mt-8">
        <NewComponentMenu />
        <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-8">{componentList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Board;
```

Comment: When you see this behavior its usually not a problem with the array modification, but a problem with setting meaningful keys in a rendered list.

Comment: Okay let me edit my post with the Board component that the items render on.

Comment: Yep. You're using `i` as the key, which is the array index. So you've told React to uniquely identify the component instances by their array index. So when you remove **any** item from the array, React just sees that the last index is missing (since they all shift down), and removes that component. Simple fix: use the `id` as the `key`.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you.  So why does it work differently when I have a todo list between 2 notes? I assume it has something to do with them being different types.

Comment: Hard to say, I don't think I'm fully understanding the other scenario. But you can read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in the React docs more about how keys work.